# Top 90% average (ASC) against group by in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I have huge database and I need to get top 90% average of all category using group by.

Example, I have 300 locations and data is around 100k with TAT column against all dockets, I need to take min 90% average of TAT all location in one query using group by(location).

Comment: which database you are using. Also show some sample data and expected output

Comment: sql server 2014, works through percent_rank. thanks

Answer (score 2):

Most DBMSes support Windowed Aggregate Fuctions, you need PERCENT_RANK:

```
select location, avg(TAT)
from
 (
   select location, TAT,
      -- assign a value between 0 (lowest TAT) and 1 (highest TAT) for each location 
      percent_rank() over (partition by location order by TAT) as pr
   from tab
 ) as dt
where pr <= 0.9 -- exclude the highest TAT amounts 
group by location
```

Comment: Thanks a lot dnoeth sir, you solved my beg problem regarding this.
i used top 90 PERCENT with ties, cume_dist but all goes in vain, thank boss once again.
will appreciate more if you tell me logic of percent_rank.

Comment: @ VishanSingh: PERCENT_RANK is the percentage of rows with a value **less than** the current one, while CUME_DIST uses **less than or equal**. See http://developer.teradata.com/blog/dnoeth/2011/05/missing-functions-cume-dist-ntile